# Compare to string of names

Tags: string, matlab

I am trying to compare the names of two strings, and trying to pick out the name that are not included in the other string.

```
h = 1;
for i = 1:name_size_main
    checker = 0;
    main_name = main(i);
    for j = 1:name_size_image
        image_name = image(j);
        temp = strcmpi(image_name, main_name);
        if temp == 1;
            checker = temp;
        end
    end
    if checker == 0
        result(h) = main_name;
        h = h+1;
    end
end
```

but it keeps returning the entire string as result, the main string contain roughly 1000 names, the images name contain about 300 names, so it should return about 700 names in result but it keep returning all 1000 names.

Comment: Please post a small example with desired inputs and output

Comment: Do you use a vector to stock your names (like `['aaa' 'bbb' 'ccc']`)?

Comment: So the input are in 300 x 1 and 1000 x 1 Cells like {'aaa','bbb','ccc'} and {'ccc','bbb'}what I desired was the 'aaa' part, the 300 x 1 cell contain 300 name that is within the 1000 x 1 cells but these name are spread randomly apart, and I want to find the 700 names that is not in the 300 x 1 cells

Comment: i figure out why is not regiestering, the 300 x 1 cells name have are 'aaa' while the 1000 x 1 names are aaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with small vectors:

```
main = ['aaa' 'bbb' 'ccc' 'ddd'];
image = ['bbb' 'ddd'];
name_size_main = size(main,2);
name_size_image = size(image,2);

h = 1;
for i = 1:name_size_main
    checker = 0;
    main_name = main(i);
    for j = 1:name_size_image
        image_name = image(j);
        temp = strcmpi(image_name, main_name);
        if temp == 1;
            checker = temp;
        end
    end
    if checker == 0
        result(h) = main_name;
        h = h+1;
    end
end
```

I get `result = 'aaaccc'`, is it not what you want to get?

EDIT:

If you are using cell arrays, you should change the line `result(h) = main_name;` to `result{h} = main_name;` like that:

```
main = {'aaa' 'bbb' 'ccc' 'ddd'};
image = {'bbb' 'ddd'};
name_size_main = size(main,2);
name_size_image = size(image,2);
result = cell(0);
h = 1;
for i = 1:name_size_main
    checker = 0;
    main_name = main(i);
    for j = 1:name_size_image
        image_name = image(j);
        temp = strcmpi(image_name, main_name);
        if temp == 1;
            checker = temp;
        end
    end
    if checker == 0
        result{h} = main_name;
        h = h+1;
    end
end
```

Comment: that is what i wanted but i am not able to get that...what i have are 1000 x1 cell and 300 x 1 cells

Answer (score 0):

You can use cells of string along with `setdiff` or `setxor`.

```
    A = cellstr(('a':'t')')  % a cell of string, 'a' to 't'
    B = cellstr(('f':'z')')  % 'f' to 'z'

    C1 = setdiff(A,B,'rows') % gives 'a' to 'e'
    C2 = setdiff(B,A,'rows') % gives 'u' to 'z'
    C3 = setxor(A,B,'rows')  % gives 'a' to 'e' and 'u' to 'z'
```

Comment: this is what i got with setdiff Input A of class cell and input B of class cell must be cell arrays of strings, unless
one is a string.